# Created bridged interface but I can't connect through it

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, network-bridge

Just to preface, I'm trying to do this on an Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 that is a VirtualBox guest on my Win10 machine.

Alright, on my Ubuntu guest, I'm trying to create a bridge interface for enp0s3 (VirtualBox bridge interface for Internet access) and enp0s8 (VirtualBox Internal network) so that I can share those interfaces with KVM guests (I'm setting up an OpenNebula environment inside VirtualBox guests).  This is my **original** /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp0s8:
      addresses: [192.168.1.55/24]
  version: 2
```

This is my **modified** /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  version: 2
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces: [enp0s3]
    br1:
      interfaces: [enp0s8]
      addresses: [192.168.1.55/24]
```

However, I have no connectivity through anything any of those interfaces now.  This is my `ifconfig` after:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::7cec:e4ff:fe4d:a771  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 7e:ec:e4:4d:a7:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 34  bytes 3446 (3.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 31  bytes 4006 (4.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.55  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::346a:7cff:fe9d:5e1d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 36:6a:7c:9d:5e:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10  bytes 816 (816.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 08:00:27:f6:23:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1428  bytes 88862 (88.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 47  bytes 5758 (5.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 08:00:27:f5:dd:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1  bytes 70 (70.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 23  bytes 2036 (2.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`brctl show`:

```
bridge name    bridge id            STP enabled    interfaces
br0            8000.7eece44da771    no             enp0s3
br1            8000.366a7c9d5e1d    no             enp0s8
virbr0         8000.52540093a24a    yes            virbr0-nic
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't enp0s3 picking up an IP, and why can't I communicate to the 192.168.1.0/24 (enp0s8) network?